# Can't figure out which AMDGPU to install for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, software-installation, graphics, opencl, amdgpu-pro

Please help me determine which AMDGPU - AMD graphic card to install so that it is compatible with the OpenCL drivers for use with Ubuntu 20.04. Also, please provide instructions on how to install the correct AMDCPU graphics card via Ubuntu terminal.

After the correct download of the AMD graphic card I will use the following command to install AMDCPU for compatibility with OpenCL drivers for my graphics card `./amdgpu-pro-install --opencl=legacy,pal –headless`

Currently, I am getting the following error messages:

```
    hashcat (v5.1.0) starting...
    
    clGetDeviceIDs(): CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND
    
    clGetDeviceIDs(): CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND
    
    OpenCL Platform #1: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc., skipped or no OpenCL compatible devices found.

OpenCL Platform #2: The pocl project
====================================
* Device #1: pthread-AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 2700U w/ Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx, 4096/13245 MB allocatable, 8MCU

    Hash 'target_hashes-2.txt': Token length exception
    No hashes loaded.
    
    Started: Sat Jul  4 19:52:30 2020
    Stopped: Sat Jul  4 19:52:30 2020
```